# Замена typedef в Java

Tags: java, c++, android-ndk

Какой аналог typedef из Си есть в Java? Или как это можно грамотно обойти?
Например, работаю с Android-NDK, в Си есть функция, ее прототип:

```
LONG List_File_Card(SCARDHANDLE gCardHandle, BYTE *buffer, DWORD *bufferLength);
```

Типы `LONG,SCARDHANDLE,BYTE,DWORD` определены в h-никах, по аналогии `typedef long LONG;`

В Java коде определяю эту же функцию как

```
public static native LONG List_File_Card(SCARDHANDLE gCardHandle, BYTE *buffer, DWORD *bufferLength);
```

Нужно, чтобы в эту функцию поступали и возвращались такие же имена типов данных, как и в Си. Как их можно и лучше определить в Java? С помощью классов, интерфейсов, enum? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: а зачем вообще переопределять тебе типы? ты  переписываешь программу на java ?

Comment: @Senior Pomidor, нужно сделать интерфейс на Java, будут вызываться функции Java, а обрабатываться на Си. Желательно, чтобы в Java использовались такие же типы данных, как и в коде на Си, но походу это невозможно.. вот и спросил

Comment: для этого используют другие механизмы. посмотрите в сторону JSON. пусть программа выдаст результат в виде JSON, если это возможно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Батенька, у вас проблема не в `typedef`, а в маппинге сишных типов на Java типы:

[Почитайте доку](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/types.html) про маппинг сишных типов на Java.

На стороне C, вы должны декларировать функцию типа:

```
jlong <имя_пакета>_List_File_Card(<blah-blah);
```

Comment: ваш ответ направил меня в нужную сторону, спасибо! Но так как я вообще новичок, то не отказался бы от подробного примера)

Answer (score 0):

`typedef`, либо похожего аналога, в Java нет.

---

Можно попробовать сделать эмуляцию через наследование:

```
public class LONG extends Long {}
```

Но это уже будет не примитивный тип, так что, я думаю, не стоит этим заниматься.